# Write a for loop to find the lengths of the vectors in a list

Tags: r, list, loops

I The Answer_vector should equal sample_lengths, which it doesn't.  My code outputs this:

[1] 32 35 39 44 39 36 46 46 46 42 46

[1] 31 33 36 40 34 30 39 38 37 32 35

```
set.seed(42)
sample_lengths <- sample(30:40)
list1 <- lapply(sample_lengths, sample) 

# create an empty vector for answers
Answer_vector <- rep(NA, length(list1))

# loop over list and find lengths
list1 <- lapply(sample_lengths, sample)

for (i in 1:length(list1)) {
      Answer_vector[i]<-sample_lengths[i]+i
    }
Answer_vector
sample_lengths
```

Comment: why not use `lengths()` ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. 1. please use `set.seed`, so we can replicate your example data. 2. Maybe use `lengths(list1)` ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. In the loop you add `i` to the ´i`th entry of `sample_length` and store it in `Answer_vector` so it is not surprising they are not equal

Comment: what about `sapply(list1, length)`?

Comment: I want to compare using a loop verses apply functions.

Comment: Compare ..... what? Do you realize that your calls to `sample` are only creating permutations of their arguments?

Comment: kath: I changed Answer_vector[i]<-sample_lengths[i]+i to Answer_vector[i]<-sample_lengths[i] and it works.  I am confused about using iterations, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples using a for loop, sapply, and lapply. All results match the values in the `sample_lengths` vector.

```
set.seed(42)
sample_lengths <- sample(30:40)
list1 <- lapply(sample_lengths, sample) 

# create an empty vector for answers
Answer_vector <- integer()

# Length of each vector using a loop
for (i in 1:length(list1)) {
  Answer_vector[i] <- length(list1[[i]])
}

# Length of each vector using sapply
sapply.answer.vector <- sapply(list1, length)


# Length of each vector using lapply
lapply.answer.vector <- unlist(lapply(list1, length))
```